# Other ways to perform tasks without loops?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and I was creating a program which would run indefinitely. Currently, the way I have the program set up is calling a certain method which would perform a task then call another method in the same class, this method would perform a task then call the initial method. This process would repeat indefinitely until I stop the compiler.

My problem is when I try to create a GUI to make my program more user friendly, once I press the initial start button this infinite loop will not allow me to perform any other actions -- including stopping the program.

There has to be another way to do this?

I apologize if this method is extremely sloppy, I sort of taught myself java from videos and looking at other programs and don't entirely understand it yet.

Comment: I would assume a non-infinite loop would work nicely if done right and you showed us the code.

Comment: Please tell us what GUI library you're using if you want more information on how to implement it on a separate thread (cf. my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run your task in a new thread, and have your GUI stuff in another thread.

Actually, if you keep working on this problem, you'll eventually invent [event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Lots of GUI based software, like Android, use this paradigm.

Comment: Thanks, quickest answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions. The first that comes to mind is that you could put whatever method needs to run forever in its own thread, and have a different thread listen for user input. This might introduce difficulties in getting the threads to interact with each other, but it would allow you to do this.

Alternatively, add a method that checks for user input and handles it inside the infinite loop of your program. something like below

```
while(true){
    //do stuff

    checkForUserInput();

    //do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to run your UI in another thread.
Many programs are based on an infinite loop (servers that keep waiting for a new user to connect for example) and your problem isn't there.

Managing the CPU time (or the core) allocated to your infinite loop and the one allocated to take care of your UI interactions is the job of the operating system, not yours : that's why your UI should run in a separate thread than your actual code.

Depending on the GUI library (Swing, ...) you're using there may be different ways to do it and the way to implement it is well answered on Stack Overflow